# nginx url alias not working

Tags: nginx, alias

I have tried multiple variations of the `URL alias` in nginx but nothing seems to work. `domain.com/store-trans/index.html` works but the alias `domain.com/retail/12/store` does not

```
server {

    listen   80;
    listen   443 default ssl;
    root /var/www/html;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/_redirects;
    port_in_redirect off;
    proxy_redirect off;
    client_max_body_size 60m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
    }

## New Alias 
    location ~ ^/store-trans/index.html {
        alias /retail/12/store;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change `alias` to `return`:

`location ~ ^/store-trans/index.html {
  return 301 /retail/12/store;
}`